# jquery word limiter?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I am looking for a jquery (or javascript) based word limiter ? searched on web but only char. limiters

please help

Thanks a lot

Comment: I assume he means a script that does not let the user enter more than the specified amount of words.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like:

```
$('input').bind('keydown', function() {
    var words = $(this).val().split(/\s/);

    if( words.length > 3 ) {
        alert('limited to three words');
        return false;
    }
});
```

example:  http://www.jsfiddle.net/4yUqL/50/

Comment: You should check if user is typing some characters, or the users can't delete text when it reaches 3 word limit.